# Bend additional arrow in circular smartdiagram

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, smartdiagram

I want to bend an additional arrow in a circular smartdiagram. How can i achieve that?

Here is how my diagram looks right now:

[image: current diagram]

Here is how it should look:

[image: expected diagram]

Here is a MWE of my current diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \smartdiagramset{
        circular final arrow disabled=true, 
        additions={
            additional arrow color=red!50,
            additional arrow tip=stealth,
            additional arrow line width=3pt,
        }
    }
    \smartdiagramadd[circular diagram:clockwise]{
        A, B, C, D
    }{}
    \smartdiagramconnect{->, shorten <=8pt, shorten >=8pt}{module3/module2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additional arrows are not bent under the option `bend left` because `\smartdiagramconnect` is implemented by `(\start)--(\end)` and not `(\start) to (\end)`. So one needs to redefine the command

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\smartdiagramconnect}{m m}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \foreach \start/\end in {#2}
  \draw[additional item arrow type,#1]
    (\start) to (\end);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Then one can use

```
\smartdiagramconnect{->, shorten <=8pt, shorten >=8pt, bend left=30}{module3/module2}
```